# powershell set-location not working

Tags: python, powershell

I am trying to connect to remote windows machine and execute a command using powershell.

I wrote a following script which takes 3 parameters which I will be using inside the script.

Script block has `set-location` which is going to set the location and on that location it will kick off the executable using command: `installutil.exe <exe name>`

Here is the script:

```
param(
    [string]$Hostname,
    [string]$Exe_Location,
    [string]$Exe_Filename  
)

Write-Host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

$pso = New-PSSessionOption –NoMachineProfile

# user crtedentials
$Username = "XXXXXXXX"
$Password = "XXXXXXXX"

# To avoid Manual entry of Username and Password
$Secure_String = convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force
$User_cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username, $Secure_String

# Create Session
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Hostname -SessionOption $pso -credential $User_cred

#Run a powershell script in the session. Anything you put in ScriptBlock { }, will run remotely on the server.
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {Set-Location $Exe_Location;InstallUtil.exe $Exe_Filename}
Write-Host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

# Remove session
Remove-PSSession $sess
```

Command to execute:

```
.\<name>.ps1 -Hostname <hostname> -Exe_Location "C:\Program Files\ABC\BCD" -Exe_Filename "test_me.exe"
```

Error is:

```
Can not process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of the argument "path" to non-null value.
+ CategoryInfo  :InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentNullException
```

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with Python?

Comment: So $EXE_LOCATION is being set on the remote computer and on the remote computer you didn't define $EXE_LOCATION. Use -ArgumentList to pass variables

Comment: 1. I am going to call this ps1 from my python thats the reason aI added but agreed nothing to do with python as of now.

Comment: 2. Didnt define $EXE_LOCATION  - I did not get it. Its there in Param. How to use argumentList

Comment: Use -ArgumentList to pass variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Exe_Location and $Exe_Filename are being created on the remote machine. Since on the remote machine those variables are not defined they therefore are empty

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {Set-Location $Exe_Location;InstallUtil.exe $Exe_Filename}
```

use -argumentlist to pass variables

```
Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {param($Exe_Location, $Exe_Filename) Set-Location $Exe_Location;InstallUtil.exe $Exe_Filename} -ArgumentList  $Exe_Location, $Exe_Filename
```

Comment: Perfect!! Got you and learned how to use argument list. Thanks a ton @ArcSet